# How to abstract a list in order to manipulate it in other functions in Clojure?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

I'm very new to functional languages and I'm attempting to implement a simple append function in Clojure. My code:

```
(defn append
  [lizt1 lizt2]
  (cond
    (empty? lizt1) lizt2
    :else (def sq (cons (first sq lizt1) (append (rest sq lizt1) lizt2)))))

(let [x (quote (1 2 3))
      y (quote (4 5 6))]
  (append (x y))) )
```

I'm receiving an

```
  clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

exception so I'm assuming that the list that I'm attempting to pass to the function is not of compatible type(like if I were to execute a list function, and try to pass that). I thought that quoting the list would make it accessible by interface functions. Can someone help me conceptualize how to abstract a list in order to manipulate its data in a separate function?

Comment: You're trying to pass a list in "function position" in the last line of your example, you want `(append x y)`. Also, please use a formatting editor to auto-format your code. I couldn't read it at all until Alan Thompson's edit, and then the problem was clear as day.

Answer (score 9):

The source of error is this call:

```
(append(x y))
```

This expression doesn't call `append` with arguments `x` and `y`, but calls `x` with argument `y` and the result of this call is used as an argument for `append`.

But `x` is a list and list can't be used as a function- that's the meaning of `clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`.

In Clojure, position of parentheses is very important and correct syntax for "call `append` with `x` and `y`" would be:

```
(append x y)
```

But there is much more to fix:

- [`quote`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote) is usually shortened as `'`:

```
'(1 2 3)
=> (1 2 3)
```

But I suggest you to use vectors, like this:

```
[1 2 3]
=> [1 2 3]
```

- You don't have to use two nested `let`s here, one [`let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) can have many bindings:

```
(let [x [1 2 3]
      y [4 5 6]]
  ...)
```

- [`Cond`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond) with only two branches is [`if`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if).
- Don't use [`def`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/def) inside [`defn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defn)- `def` creates a global variable. When you really need to create some variables inside function, use `let`.

Solution you're looking for looks like this:

```
(defn append [col1 col2]
  (if (empty? col1) 
    col2
    (cons (first col1)
          (append (rest col1) col2))))
                    
(let [x [1 2 3]
      y [4 5 6]]
  (append x y))
=> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

(There's an even more idiomatic version with [`seq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/seq), but [`empty?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/empty_q) also works.)

Note that there's a function [`concat`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/concat) which does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, this was an extremely helpful answer.